# How do I assign an one-dimensional range to a two-dimensional array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Let's say I have a a range variable `aRange = range("A1:D1")`, and a dynamic array `Dim result() As Variant`, `redim result(1 to 2, 1 to 5)`, what's the best way to copy `aRange` to the first row of array `result`, from element (1, 2) to element (1, 5)? Assume result(1, 1) is temporarily empty. Basically, I am asking assigning a range object's value to an empty array using slicing.

Comment: Unfortunately, AFAIK, the easiest way to populate **part** of an array is a loop.

Comment: First off, `aRange = range("A1:D1")` produces a 2-D array; albeit `1 to 1, 1 to 4` not a 1-D array of `0 to 3` or `1 to 4`. Now you can sometimes slice a piece of a multi-row/multi-column array into a single-row/multi-column but you cannot 'stuff' a single-row/multi-column into a specific 'slice' of a multi-row/multi-column array. Use a loop; it's in memory and any possible advantage of 'slicing it in' would be lost in the overhead doing exactly what the loop is doping anyways.

Comment: @Jeeped Interesting, I thought VBA's arrays work as well as those in MATLAB and Python. BTW, may I ensure that `aRange` is `1 to 1, 1 to 4` rather than `0 to 0, 0 to 3`?

Comment: Yes, assigning the values from a range of single-row/multi-column or multi-row/single-column into a variant (aka *array*) will produce a 1-based index of 1 to 1, 1 to 4 or 1 to 4, 1 to 1 regardless of what `Option Base` is set for (and it defaults to zero).

Comment: Some code I like to use to confirm variant arrays after they have been stuffed with cell values: `debug.print lbound(aRange , 1) & ":" & ubound(aRange , 1)` then `debug.print lbound(aRange , 2) & ":" & ubound(aRange , 2)` but a Watch works just as well.

Comment: And, of course, you can use `aRange = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:D1")))` to get a Variant array which is dimensioned `1 To 4`.  (But is your `aRange` a variant?  Or is it a `Range` variable?)

Comment: What happened? Two transposes transforms a 1 by 4 two-dimensional array to  a one-dimensional array!@YowE3K

Comment: @YowE3K - if the latter then `Set` should be used. I believe it is a variant that is relying on the default `.Value` property of a range.

Comment: @Jeeped I interpreted the question originally as "I have a `Range` variable `aRange` which is equal to `range("A1:D1")`, but agree that it could also be interpreted as "I have a `Variant` variable storing the values of a range which I have created using `aRange = range("A1:D1")`.  My comment was mainly to make the OP realise that `aRange = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:D1")))` would only work if it was the latter interpretation.

Comment: @Nicholas - yes, two transposes of a `1 To 1, 1 To x` array will yield a `1 To x` array.  That's because one transpose of a `1 To x, 1 To 1` array (such as you get if you read a column of data into a Variant array) yields a `1 To x` array.  Isn't VBA fun!